# How to insert a colon between word and number

Tags: perl

I want to insert a colon between word and number then add a new line after a number.
For example:

```
"cat 11052000 cow_and_owner_ 01011999 12031981 dog 22032011";
```

my expected output:

```
cat:11052000
cow_and_owner_:01011999 12031981
dog:22032011
```

My attempt :

```
$Bday=~ /^([a-z]||\_)/:/^([0-9])/
print "\n";
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What's the result?

Comment: Your example is just printing a newline. Surely, you aren't needing to print "$Bday\n". As @Matt asked, what is your result and how is it wrong?

Comment: Sorry Matt and UncleCarl , I am getting syntax error at script.pl line 13, near "/^([a-z]||\_)/:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $str = "cat 11052000 cow_and_owner_ 01011999 12031981 dog 22032011";
$str =~ s/\s*([a-z_]+)((?: \d+)+)/$1:$2\n/g;
print $str;
```

produces your desired output from your sample input.

Edit: Note the use of the `s` operator for regular expression substitution. One of the many problems with your code is that you're not using that (IF your intent is to modify the string in place and not extract bits from it for further processing)

Comment: Thank you Shawn, your code works perfectly. Ya, i just realize the s operator is missing in my code.  However, my code cannot get the output if the  "cat" changed to "cat[1]" and "dog" changed to "dog3". 
I tried to use : str =~ s/\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_ \]]+)((?: \d+)+)/$1:$2\n/g;
but im getting 
cat[]: 11052000 "\n"
 cow_and_owner_01011999 12031981 dog3: 22032011.

Comment: May i know what is the meaning of  "?:" in the bracket? Appreciate if you can help to explain

Comment: @thx94 A regular `(...)` is a capture group, meaning the contents will be placed in variables `$1`, `$2`, etc. depending on the order of appearance. `(?:...)` makes the group non-capturing, allowing you to just group and multiply or make optional complex things without capturing them.

Comment: An example would be that to match either the word "child" or the plural "children", you could use a regex pattern `/\bchild(?:ren)?\b/`, which groups the "ren" and makes it optional as a whole (and not each letter separately). Most of the times you wouldn't want to capture the "ren" unless you were checking for the presence of the plural. (The `\b` or some other method of checking for word boundaries are needed to avoid matching "childless" or "Fairchild".)

Answer (score 0):

One more variant -

```
> cat test_perl.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while ( "cat 11052000 cow_and_owner_ 01011999 12031981 dog 22032011" =~ m/([a-z_]+)\s+([0-9 ]+)/g )
{
print "$1:$2\n";
}
> test_perl.pl
cat:11052000
cow_and_owner_:01011999 12031981
dog:22032011
>
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code `$Bday=~ /^([a-z]||\_)/:/^([0-9])/` doesn't make much sense. Apart from missing a semicolon and having too many delimiters (matching patterns are of the format `/.../` or `m/.../` and replacing ones `s/.../.../`), it could never match anything.

1. `([a-z]||\_)` would match:

   - one lowercase ASCII letter (a through z);
   - an empty string (the space between the two `|`s; or
   - one underscore (escape with a backslash is superfluous).

   To get it (or the corresponding subexpression for numbers) to match a sequence of one 
   or more of the characters, you need to follow it with a `+`.
2. `^([0-9])` would fail to match unless it was at the beginning of the string. There it would match a single digit.

---

My solution (taking into account the later comments by the OP about having input such as `cat[1]` or `dog3`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bday = "cat 11052000 cow_and_owner_ 01011999 12031981 dog 22032011 cat[1] 01012018 dog3 02012018";

# capture groups:
#          $1------------------------\   $2-------------\
$bday =~ s/([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_\[\]]*)\h+(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)(?!\S)\s*/$1:$2\n/g;

print $bday;
```

will print out:

```
cat:11052000
cow_and_owner_:01011999 12031981
dog:22032011
cat[1]:01012018
dog3:02012018
```

Breakdown:

- `[A-Za-z]`: Begin with a letter.
- `[A-Za-z0-9_\[\]]*`: Follow with zero or more letters, numbers, underscores and square brackets.
- `\h+`: Separate with one or more horizontal whitespace.
- `\d+(?:\h+\d+)*`: One sequence of digits (`\d+`) followed by zero or more sequences of horizontal whitespace and digits.
- `(?!\S)`: Can't be followed by non-whitespace.
- `\s*`: Consume following whitespace (including line feeds; this allows the input to be separated on multiple lines, as long as a single entry is not spread on multiple lines. To get that, replace all the `\h+` with `\s+`.).

The replace pattern will repeat (the `/g` modifier) sequentially in the source string as long as it matches, placing each heading-date record on its own line and then proceeding with the rest of the string.

---

Note that if your headers (`dog` etc.) might contain non-ASCII letters, use `\pL` or `\p{XPosixAlpha}` instead of `[A-Za-z]`:

```
$bday =~ s/\pL[\pL0-9_\[\]]*)\h+(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)(?!\S)\s*/$1:$2\n/g;
```